# 403 Forbidden Error for All Directories Starting with "web_"

Tags: .htaccess

I want to disable directory browsing for all my directories. I managed to do that with:

 `Options -Indexes` in my .htaccess file.

However, I have directories that belong to addon domains so whenever someone tries to access those directories, it redirects it to the index file of that page, so it doesn't show a 403 forbidden error.

How can I show a 403 forbidden error for those addon domain directories that start with "web_"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand with "addon domains" you are referring to subdomains, i.e. a folder like `/sub_a` should be accessible as `sub_a.example.org`, but should show a 403-error if it is accessed as `example.org/sub_a`.

If this is the case, there are many options.

For instance, you could add a .htaccess file into these folders, where access via `example.org/sub_a` is either redirected to `sub_a.example.org`, rather than just showing a 403.

Or you could use @Salman A's answer and use [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#locationmatch) instead of DirectoryMatch, which would only trigger if the folder is used as part of an URL.

Or you could also modify your index file (e.g. if it's a php-script) to either return a 403-header, redirect or do something completely different.